# Changes to GDAL NetCDF driver between 3.2 and 3.4

Tags: gdal, netcdf, rioxarray, xarray

I am preparing data in python using xarray and rioxarray, then exporting to NetCDF. On one machine with

```
micha@RMS:Kinneret$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.2.2, released 2021/03/05
```

the extent of the resulting *.nc is correct, and displays as expected in QGIS.
Here's the reported extent:

```
micha@RMS:Kinneret$ gdalinfo NETCDF:"Kinneret_velocity.nc":u | grep -A 4 Corner
Warning 1: dimension #2 (x) is not a Longitude/X dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #1 (y) is not a Latitude/Y dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #0 (z) is not a Time or Vertical dimension.
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  735758.000, 3644806.000) ( 35d31'15.70"E, 32d54'57.98"N)
Lower Left  (  735758.000, 3621606.000) ( 35d30'54.46"E, 32d42'25.30"N)
Upper Right (  754558.000, 3644806.000) ( 35d43'18.74"E, 32d54'42.80"N)
Lower Right (  754558.000, 3621606.000) ( 35d42'55.82"E, 32d42'10.25"N)
```

However when I start a conda env with an updated GDAL:

```
(geo) micha@RMS:Kinneret$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.5.2, released 2022/09/02
```

the corners revert to the dimension sizes:

```
(geo) micha@RMS:Kinneret$ gdalinfo NETCDF:"Kinneret_velocity.nc":u | grep -A 4 Corner
Warning 1: dimension #2 (x) is not a Longitude/X dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #1 (y) is not a Latitude/Y dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #0 (z) is not a Time or Vertical dimension.
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,   58.0)
Upper Right (   47.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (   47.0,   58.0)
```

The same thing happened in another machine with a newer GDAL. And with these environments, in QGIS the NetCDF variables appear around (0,0).

What am I missing in the xarray DataSet? Were there any changes in recent versions of GDAL that I need to be aware of?

Here's the full ncdump:

```
(geo) micha@RMS:Kinneret$ ncdump -h "Kinneret_velocity.nc"
netcdf Kinneret_velocity {
dimensions:
        x = 47 ;
        y = 58 ;
        z = 36 ;
variables:
        int x(x) ;
                x:long_name = "x-coordinate" ;
                x:units = "m" ;
                x:grid_mapping = "spatial_ref" ;
        int y(y) ;
                y:long_name = "y-coordinate" ;
                y:units = "m" ;
                y:grid_mapping = "spatial_ref" ;
        int spatial_ref ;
                spatial_ref:crs_wkt = "PROJCS[\"WGS 84 / UTM zone 36N\",GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",33],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",500000],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],AXIS[\"Easting\",EAST],AXIS[\"Northing\",NORTH],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"32636\"]]" ;
                spatial_ref:semi_major_axis = 6378137. ;
                spatial_ref:semi_minor_axis = 6356752.31424518 ;
                spatial_ref:inverse_flattening = 298.257223563 ;
                spatial_ref:reference_ellipsoid_name = "WGS 84" ;
                spatial_ref:longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0. ;
                spatial_ref:prime_meridian_name = "Greenwich" ;
                spatial_ref:geographic_crs_name = "WGS 84" ;
                spatial_ref:horizontal_datum_name = "World Geodetic System 1984" ;
                spatial_ref:projected_crs_name = "WGS 84 / UTM zone 36N" ;
                spatial_ref:grid_mapping_name = "transverse_mercator" ;
                spatial_ref:latitude_of_projection_origin = 0. ;
                spatial_ref:longitude_of_central_meridian = 33. ;
                spatial_ref:false_easting = 500000. ;
                spatial_ref:false_northing = 0. ;
                spatial_ref:scale_factor_at_central_meridian = 0.9996 ;
                spatial_ref:spatial_ref = "PROJCS[\"WGS 84 / UTM zone 36N\",GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",33],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",500000],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],AXIS[\"Easting\",EAST],AXIS[\"Northing\",NORTH],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"32636\"]]" ;
        float Long(y, x) ;
                Long:_FillValue = NaNf ;
                Long:long_name = "longitude coords" ;
                Long:units = "deg" ;
                Long:grid_mapping = "spatial_ref" ;
        float Lat(y, x) ;
                Lat:_FillValue = NaNf ;
                Lat:long_name = "latitude coords" ;
                Lat:units = "deg" ;
                Lat:grid_mapping = "spatial_ref" ;
        int z(z) ;
        double u(z, y, x) ;
                u:_FillValue = NaN ;
                u:long_name = "u component of velocity" ;
                u:units = "m sec-1" ;
                u:grid_mapping = "spatial_ref" ;
        double v(z, y, x) ;
                v:_FillValue = NaN ;
                v:long_name = "v component of velocity" ;
                v:units = "m sec-1" ;
                v:grid_mapping = "spatial_ref" ;

// global attributes:
                :Conventions = "CF-1.10" ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the related issue: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/4075

The solution is to use `rio.write_coordinate_system`:
https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/getting_started/crs_management.html#Spatial-dimensions

Comment: That was it. The full command that I did:

`DS.rio.write_crs(
    f'EPSG:{projected_epsg}',
    inplace=True).rio.set_spatial_dims(
        x_dim="x", y_dim="y", inplace=True`
        ).rio.write_coordinate_system(inplace=True)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked 

Comment: If it worked I suggest to accept the answer!